# SortByKey() for a Key having more than 10 Elements

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I have been using `sortByKey()` for sorting my Key Values which are a tuple. If the size of the tuple is less than 9 then the `sortByKey` function works fine. But at size 10 the `sortByKey()` method fails.
How do we print sorted keys which are a tuple of size 10 or more.

Working example if I do the print as follows for RDD with key of size 9:

```
scala> freq_9s
res31: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int), Int)]
scala> var frequent_movie_9s_count=freq_9s.count().toInt

scala> printf(freq_9s.sortByKey().take(frequent_movie_9s_count).map({case (x,_) => s"$x" }).mkString(","))
(98,102,103,107,108,109,112,113,114),(98,102,106,107,108,109,112,113,114),(98,102,107,108,109,112,113,114,115),(99,100,102,103,104,107,108,110,114),(99,100,102,103,104,107,108,110,116),(99,100,102,103,104,107,108,114,116))
```

I want to do the same thing but this time my RDD looks:

```
scala> freq_10s
res31: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int), Int)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OrderedRDDFunctions.sortByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions) depend on an implicit `Ordering[K]` and Scala provides ordering only for `Tuples` up to [`Tuple9`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L472-L495).

For larger tuples you have to provide your own implicit ordering, for example using built-in `Orderings` as a template.

```
implicit val ordTN: Ordering[(T1, T2, ..., TN) = ???
```

You can also convert to `DataFrame` and convert back to `RDD` when needed.

```
freq_9s.orderBy($"k").as[((Int, ..., Int), Int)].rdd
```